# NullPointerException on SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase when triggered from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error here:

```
com.mysite.datasources.ArticlesDataSource.open(ArticlesDataSource.java:88)
```

The code is this:

```
public void open() throws SQLException
{
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //this is line 88
}
```

It's being called from the `importArticles()` function within `ArticlesDataSource`.

This works fine when called from my `SplashScreenActivity`:

```
articlesDataSource = new ArticlesDataSource(context);
try {
    articlesDataSource.importArticles(Section.currentSection, false);
    ...
```

But when I try to call it from my `ImportArticlesAsync` (within `MainActivity`), I get the `NullPointerException` error.

```
//This is within my MainActivity class

    //...
    ImportArticlesAsync importArticlesAsync = new ImportArticlesAsync(this);
    importArticlesAsync.execute("");
}

private class ImportArticlesAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    Context mContext;
    //ProgressDialog waitSpinner;
    private ArticlesDataSource articlesDataSource;
    //ConfigurationContainer configuration = ConfigurationContainer.getInstance();

    public ImportArticlesAsync(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        //waitSpinner = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        //IMPORTS THE ARTICLES FROM THE RSS FEED (adds or updates)
    //tried just mContext //notice
    //tried mContext.getApplicationContext() //ERROR / crash

        articlesDataSource = new ArticlesDataSource(mContext);
        try {
            articlesDataSource.importArticles(Section.currentSection, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                    mContext,
                    "NOTICE: Could not import/update " + Section.currentSection.toString() + " articles.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //loads article from database to the list
        loadArticlesIntoList(Section.currentSection);
}
}
```

From what I've read, most people think it must be incorrect context.  But - I don't really understand contexts yet, and have tried every way I can think of (and read a lot about contexts).

---

**My attempt at a diagram / cleaner explanation of my "code":**

```
//YAY this works!
SplashScreenActivity
    -LoadApplication (AsyncTask)
        -doInBackground
             articlesDataSource = new ArticleDataSource(context);
             articlesDataSource.importArticles(Section.currentSection, false);

//BOO, this doesn't work!
MainActivity
    -ImportArticlesAsync
        -doInBackground (AsyncTask)
             articlesDataSource = new ArticlesDataSource(context);
             articlesDataSource.importArticles(Section.currentSection, false);
```

---

**Per request - dbHelper getting set here:**

```
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DbHelper dbHelper;
private PhotosDataSource photosdatasource;
private SectionsDataSource sectionsdatasource;

public ArticlesDataSource(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(mContext);
    photosdatasource = new PhotosDataSource(context);
    sectionsdatasource = new SectionsDataSource(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException
{
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

---

**Code:**

com.mysite.news

- SplashScreenActivity.java - http://pastebin.com/ZaunrrzY
- MainActivity.java - http://pastebin.com/k08sDLaJ

com.mysite.models

- Article.java - http://pastebin.com/SBEqrCuw
- Photo.java - http://pastebin.com/75DVzK6Z
- Section.java - http://pastebin.com/0YYkk5JQ

com.mysite.datasources

- ArticlesDataSource.java - http://pastebin.com/bFM4G0xT
- SectionsDataSource.java - http://pastebin.com/pKZQHt9U
- PhotosDataSource.java - http://pastebin.com/sZTZd4ZP

com.mysite.utilites

- DbHelper.java - http://pastebin.com/PMCFrVyG

AndroidManifest.xml - http://pastebin.com/hHF86f4d

---

**ERROR:**

07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at com.mysite.datasources.ArticlesDataSource.open(ArticlesDataSource.java:88)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at com.mysite.datasources.ArticlesDataSource.importArticles(ArticlesDataSource.java:101)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at com.mysite.news.MainActivity$ImportArticlesAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:194)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at com.mysite.news.MainActivity$ImportArticlesAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-20 21:33:26.721: W/System.err(8260):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

---

**SectionSelectedListener.java**

```
package com.mysite.news;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class SectionSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
    {
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.sectionSelected();     
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // Do nothing       
    }

}
```

Comment: it seems like the dbHelper variable is null. can you show us where that value is assigned?

Comment: is it safe to assume that DbHelper is a class that overrides SQLiteDatabaseHelper?

Comment: mfrankli - "public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper"

Comment: What context are you passing to your ArticlesDataSource? (which is being used to create the SQLiteOpenHelper)

Comment: You should call super(context) in your constructor for ImportArticleAsync

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot that was type specified. Is there a way I can just view all your code on git or something? trying to piece these bits and pieces it far too difficult..

Comment: Joel - I added a lot of code links at the bottom.  I think I got all the relevant files, but if there's ANYTHING I can do to help you help me, please let me know!  (pls don't laugh at my code - this is my first android app)

Comment: @Dave Can you post your full stacktrace with the exception? I have serious doubts that `dbHelper` is `null` in the `open()` method, on the other hand a `null` `Context` will make the `getWritableDatabase` throw a `NullPointerException`(as it uses that `Context` to initialize the database). Also add the code for the `SectionSelectedListener` listener(I guess from there you call the method `sectionSelected`?!?)

Comment: Luksprog - added both the stacktrace and the listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Context` reference that you pass to the `AsyncTask` is `null`. The problem appears from you instantiating a new `MainActivity` just to call the `sectionSelected()` method. You should never instantiate an activity by yourself!

The simplest solution would be to simple make an anonymous inner class as the listener in the `MainActivity`:

```
sectionsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
       sectionSelected();     
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // Do nothing       
    }

});
```

Comment: @Dave Quick copy pasting left those parenthesis out :). Moving the importing of articles to another thread should also solve your previous problem with the `ListView` not disappearing.

Comment: Luksprog - I think my articles import IS in a different thread now, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line `articlesDataSource = new ArticlesDataSource(mContext);` from the `doInBackground(..)` method of your `AsyncTask` to the `onPreExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask`. Something like this:

```
private class ImportArticlesAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

Context mContext;
//ProgressDialog waitSpinner;
private ArticlesDataSource articlesDataSource;
//ConfigurationContainer configuration = ConfigurationContainer.getInstance();

public ImportArticlesAsync(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    //waitSpinner = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
   articlesDataSource = new ArticlesDataSource(mContext);
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{        
    try {
        articlesDataSource.importArticles(Section.currentSection, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                mContext,
                "NOTICE: Could not import/update " + Section.currentSection.toString() + " articles.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    //loads article from database to the list
    loadArticlesIntoList(Section.currentSection);
}
}
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Where do you save your database? If you save it in the assets folder on your project, then you only have read permissions to files and not write.

Comment: Also are you passing the right context as parameter in your `AsyncTask`? Maybe you are still passing the `SplashScreenActivity's` context and not the `MainActivity's` context which is the right one in your second use case.

Comment: Angelo - 1) I have write permissions - my app creates and populates the database.  2) that's my exact question - I have no idea what context to send or if I"m sending the right one

Comment: You have to send your current Activity's context in your case the `MainActivity's` context. If your AsyncTask is being called inside the `MainActivity` you can just call it passing `MainActivity.this` or `MainActivity.this.getBaseContext()` as it's context parameter. If you are calling your AsyncTask outside the `MainActivity`, you can keep a reference of the MainActivity's context.

Comment: Angelo - per my question, I'm calling it within an AsyncTask that's within my MainActivity.  I've tried 100 different things, and can't get any to work - I'm just looking for "Try this (something specific)"

Comment: Then in your case, call your `ImportArticlesAsync` like this: `ImportArticlesAsync task = new ImportArticlesAsync(MainActivity.this); task.excecute(new String[] {your_params});` I apologize if i get something wrong.

Comment: I changed "this" to "MainActivity.this", but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Joel There is a reason this approach exists(`ClassName.this`). In cases that you have nested classes sometimes the `this` variable does not take the "desired" or "correct" class instance as reference. Using this approach you ensure the correct class reference in the `this` variable. But i admit that in this case it turned out to be useless:S

Comment: I understand what it is for... and it wasn't a bad idea to check, he could have had that in an onClick() function or something he created a listener for, that's why i deleted my comment, haha.  This is a difficult thing to analyze without seeing his full code.

Answer (score 0):

move dbHelper variable from your ArticlesDataSource class to your Activity, ensure it gets initialized before you create the AsyncTasks.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't follow what you're saying.  This all works perfectly fine the first time I run it, but then second time, from the MainActivity (as opposed to the SplashScreenActivity), it fails.